# Combine 2 columns for unique value to out output sum

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fetch specific values in column "A" that is using the data below if Column A = "EAST01" then combine or column "B" and "C", count the number of unique occurrences output in Column "I" (TOTAL_TRAILERS) and sum the values in Column "D" (DOCK_TIME), output in Column "J" (TOTAL_DOCK_TIME)

So far this code yields gives me the unique values but I am struggling to figure out where to insert the if statement to get only 'EAST01' and the calculation to get the output.
Since i will be receiving this file everyday, i would like the additional output not to overwrite my previous output but print on the next row under the previous "TOTAL_TRAILERS" and "TOTAL_DOCK_TIME".
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

sample Data

```
STORE   TRAILER REC_DATE            DOCK_TIME
EAST01  648295  6/7/2019 10:12:13 AM    19
WEST03  671649  6/7/2019 10:14:47 AM    18
CENTRAL1 V18070 6/7/2019 10:23:31 AM    21
SOUTH04 671652  6/7/2019 10:27:59 AM    22
EAST01  648295  6/7/2019 10:54:12 AM    22
EAST01  648295  6/7/2019 12:03:04 PM    24
EAST01  62517   6/7/2019 12:03:37 PM    23
```

---

```
Sub unikAndSum()

    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, r As Range
    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'With ws
    'N=.Range("A" & .rows.count.end(xlup).row
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 3)
        Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 5)
    Next i
    'Range("F:F").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    For Each r In Range("F:F").SpecialCells(2).Offset(, 1)
        r.Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E," & r.Offset(, -1).Address & ")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

```
       TOTAL_TRAILER           TOTAL_DOCK_TIME
                  4                        88
```

Next day output here>

Comment: Don't you just need SUMIF?

Comment: @SJR Do you mean instead of Count if? Also, I want to include "EAST01" store only in the calculation. I am wondering where to include the if statement to only calculate for "EAST01" only.

Answer (score 0):

The value EAST01 that you are looking for is in Cells(i,1)

The If Statement is in the For Loop

Modified in response to your followup question about the countif slowing down your program.

You can eliminate the for loop because all that the countif statements are doing is putting a 1 in column G.  There is no need to do a countif, just put a 1 in column G within the if statement.

Cells(i, 7) = 1

```
    Sub unikAndSum()

    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, r As Range
    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'With ws
    'N=.Range("A" & .rows.count.end(xlup).row
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If (Cells(i, 1) = "EAST01") Then
        Cells(i, 5) = Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 3)
        Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 5)
        Cells(i, 7) = 1
        End If
    Next i
    'Range("F:F").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    'For Each r In Range("F:F").SpecialCells(2).Offset(, 1)
    '    r.Formula = "=COUNTIF(E:E," & r.Offset(, -1).Address & ")"
    'Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @jeffld it works, how can I sum up the columns DOCK_TIME of only EAST01? Also the I believe COUNTIF is slowing the calculation big time, how can I use evaluate instead?

Comment: Average of 2500